# Which status-code for a currently (intended) unavailable page

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Currently I'm building a website where you can win a prize everyday. You can only participate on the given day, e.g. having the days 1st to 7th you could only open Day 5 on the 5th.

My URLs are something like www.example.org/day/5

Now let's say it is the 5th and I would try to open the URL www.example.org/day/12. Of course this shouldn't work but which status-code should be returned? Especially as after the 12th the day is accessible.

I guess a redirection or a client error would be appropriate, but I don't know which one exactly.

Comment: how about 403 Forbidden?

Comment: Of course that would be obvious, I could also go with 423 locked. I'm looking more for an detailed explanation why to use which code.

Comment: If the user deliberately calls a wrong url, Forbidden could be a nice "go away" signal (especially in websites where prizes are involved...)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that will do, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of page, you should use the "Client Error 4xx" class of status codes.
I guess a "403 Forbidden" would be great here.
For you to know, the 403 Forbidden error means that the server understood what you wanted to get, but makes the page unavailable for the user, even with authentification. Depending on how much information you want to give to the user, you can use 404 Not Found too, telling the user that there's nothing to be found here. 403 provides more like a "This page exists, but you can't go to it" meanwhile 404 provides a "I don't know what you're talking about".